# ING Postident with austrian passport

Tags: banking, germany

My girlfriend wants to open a bank account with ING. We both live in germany. Now she has to verify her identity by Postident. However, it's not working out so well with her austrian passport(Reisepass).

She has already tried in two different post offices. There, they said that the scanner wouldn't recognize the passport or that the passport was too new.
There are also problems with the video chat via smartphone. Before the video chat starts, she has to take a photo of her passport. Even then, the passport is not recognized correctly and she cannot proceed.
[This pdf from Deutsche Post](https://www.deutschepost.de/dam/jcr:2f2c2ca3-f3c3-40a2-911e-4916dc1af7ef/dp-postident-ausweisliste-filiale.pdf) states, that a austrian passport should be accepted.

Upon inquiry via email, ING replied that there is no alternative to Postident.

Does anyone know a solution to the problem, or does she have to go to another bank?

---

Meine Freundin möchte ein Girokonto bei der ING eröffnen. Wir wohnen beide in Deutschland. Jetzt muss sie sich per Postident legitimieren. Mit ihrem österreichischen Reisepass funktioniert das aber nicht so recht.

Sie hat es schon in zwei verschiedenen Postfilialen versucht. Dort hieß es dann, der Scanner würde den Reisepass nicht erkennen bzw. der Reisepass sei zu neu.
Beim Videochat per Smartphone gibts auch Probleme. Bevor der Videochat losgeht, muss sie den Reisepass abfotografieren. Auch da wird der Reisepass nicht richtig erkannt und kann nicht fortfahren.
Laut [Übersicht über die akzeptierten Ausweise](https://www.deutschepost.de/dam/jcr:2f2c2ca3-f3c3-40a2-911e-4916dc1af7ef/dp-postident-ausweisliste-filiale.pdf) von der Post sollte ein Reisepass aber akzeptiert werden.

Auf Nachfrage per E-Mail antwortet die ING, dass es keine Alternative zum Postident gibt.

Kennt jemand eine Lösung für das Problem oder muss sie zu einer anderen Bank?

Comment: Unresearch, but I would try the ID (Personalausweis) instead of the passport, maybe it would pass

Comment: Yeah maybe. Unfortunately she doesn't have a Personalausweis, only a Reisepass.

Comment: While you try to solve that, I would highly suggest her to get it, It is **always** good to have a second piece of ID, especially one that is recognized around Europe. Main issue is that it's extortionately expensive though (62€)